# Android - Select file from internal storage folder

Tags: android

I have saved a bunch of videos in an internal storage folder. Afterwards, I want the user to be able to select one of these videos in this specific folder. I tried using ACTION_GET_CONTENT in an attempt to let another app do this for me, without any success, as it just opens up a file browser in some other directory.

What I have now is:

```
public static File getOwnVideosDirectory(Context context) {
    String ownVideosDirPath =
            context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "OwnVideos";
    File ownVideosDir = new File(ownVideosDirPath);
    if (!ownVideosDir.exists()) {
        ownVideosDir.mkdirs();
    }
    return ownVideosDir;
}

private void dispatchExistingVideo() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "> dispatchExistingVideo");
    Intent videoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    File ownVideosDir = Utility.getOwnVideosDirectory(getContext());
    videoPicker.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(ownVideosDir), "video/*");
    if (videoPicker.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(videoPicker, REQUEST_EXISTING_VIDEO);
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering, am I doing something wrong or is it impossible like this. If impossible: is there any library,... available that would allow me to do what I want, or any direction on how I could implement this myself as a last resort?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "am I doing something wrong or is it impossible like this" -- third-party apps have no access to your files in `getFilesDir()`. "is there any library" -- asking for recommendations of libraries is off-topic for Stack Overflow. That being said, [here are ten or so](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at that library - [Material File Picker](https://github.com/nbsp-team/MaterialFilePicker)
It allows to show a dialog with the specified path using `.withPath(Utility.getOwnVideosDirectory(getContext()).getAbsolutePath())`.

The whole creation code:

```
new MaterialFilePicker()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withRequestCode(1)
    .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.txt$")) // Filtering files and directories by file name using regexp
    .withFilterDirectories(true) // Set directories filterable (false by default)
    .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folders
    .withPath(Utility.getOwnVideosDirectory(getContext()).getAbsolutePath())
    .start();
```